# How can I route a specific entry in a structure section to its own template?

Tags: templating, structure, custom, routing

While setting up a site recently I wanted to route a specific entry in a structure section to its own custom template. Using a dynamic route sounded like the right option until I remembered that it wouldn't work due to Craft's routing order (matched entry uri comes before matched template).

I considered adding a conditional redirect to the structure's generic template but this feels a bit dirty. Does anyone have a better solution of how to make this work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The cleanest way I have found to achieve this is to create a generic template for the structure as well as a custom template for each entry that needs one, ensuring that its path matches the entry's uri.

I then put this single line of code in the structure's selected template and it works beautifully:

```
{% extends [entry.uri, '_generic'] %}
```

This should work as well:

```
{% include [entry.uri, '_generic'] %}
```

If the entry's uri exists as a template route then it will be rendered, otherwise the generic template will be.

**UPDATE:**

I recently extended this on a site to allow for unique custom pages, custom entry type pages and a fallback generic page:

```
{% extends [
    '_custom/' ~ entry.slug,
    '_entrytypes/' ~ entry.type,
    '_generic'
] %}
```

Comment: That's very clever! Per the Twig docs, "The first template that exists will be used as a parent".
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance

Comment: In my opinion, this should be marked as the best answer. You may also want to share this "recipe" on http://craftcookbook.net/

Comment: Im having a bit of a problem managing this method where  the entry.uri file needs to extend blocks in the main file.  Any ideas?

Comment: no, not in the scenario above

Comment: If your entries are in Structure, and some pages need to use different template, you can use this code in your 'main' template defined in section settings. ``{% extends [
    craft.request.path,
    '_generic'
] %}``

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the conditional redirect is the best way. You can use it to load a template dynamically in the structure's generic _entry template using the include tag.

My suggestion would be to add a lightswitch field that tells the entry to load a custom template. Then in the _entry template do something like this:

```
{% if entry.customTemplate %}
    {% include "section/_" ~ entry.slug %}
{% else %}
    {% include "section/_generic" %}
{% endif %}
```

This is the same basic idea used in Pixel & Tonic's help page on [using different templates for different entry types](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-templates).

Comment: thanks bryan, this is close to what i did except that i managed to drop the conditional and use an array in the include in its place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Call the generic template `_route.html`, and have it do nothing but `{%extends ...%}` to route to the template you want.