# Overriding a structure section's template for a single structure entry

Tags: structure, routing

When you create a structure section you set which template that you would like to use. Is there a way to override that for a single entry in that structure? If I have missed it in the docs I apologise but it would appear that setting a [route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) would not work due to the order things are looked up at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my answer here should provide you with exactly what you need, as well as an elegant and reusable way to do it:

[How can I route a specific entry in a structure section to its own template?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-route-a-specific-entry-in-a-structure-section-to-its-own-template)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) to load different templates conditionally like so:

```
{% if entry.id == '24' %}
    {% include "_entries/mystructure_special" %}
{% else %}
    {% include "_entries/mystructure_base" %}
{% endif %}
```

Also consider if it makes sense to add a new [Entry Type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#entry-types) for this one entry and then set things up per this tutorial: ["How can I give each Entry Type its own template?"](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-templates).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @carlcs Ben's approach worked really well for me in this instance.