# Overriding Craft's default routing process

Tags: routes, routing

I have a situation where I'd like to have an entry exist with a particular URL structure by placing it within an existing structure. Let's say this URI is:

```
/one/two/three
```

Where 'three' is the entry I've created in the CP. Currently, this structure uses this section's template, but I'd like to use a unique template for this single entry within the section. My first thought was to create a Dynamic Route that points this URI to the unique template, but that doesn't work.

It seems that Craft has a checklist of items for routing and a section's template will be checked for first, and if that exists, it gets loaded. Is it possible to override this and load a unique template for a single entry in a section?

Comment: Should have looked harder! This solves my problem:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-route-a-specific-entry-in-a-structure-section-to-its-own-template

Comment: Good find! Closing this one as a dupe. :)